Integral of two independent Gaussian with different mean
I am trying to solve the following integral:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-c\left\vert x\right\vert}^{c\left\vert x\right\vert}
\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma^{2}}\,
\exp\left(-\frac{\left[y - \theta\,\right]^{2} + x^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}\right){\rm d}y\,{\rm d}x
$$
for some $c > 0,\ \theta > 0$ and $\sigma^{2} > 0$.
I am trying to solve it using polar coordinate
$$
x = r\cos\left(\phi\right),\,\,\,  y = r\sin\left(\phi\right) \quad\mbox{for}\quad \phi \in \left[0,2\pi\right)\ \mbox{and}\ r \in \left[0,\infty\right)
$$
but I got stucked writing the extremes of integration in the inner integral.
Can you help me please ?. Best !.

Unless that $-x^2$ is a typo for $+x^2$ in the exponent, that is not a joint Gaussian pdf in the integral.

Yes it is a typo, thanks!

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49380/polar-coordinates-of-gaussian-distribution-with-non-zero-mean?rq=1

The difference here is the the extremes of integration of the inner integral are not $\pm \infty$. If you try to pass to the polar coordinates it is not trivial to find the corresponding extremes.

Where does this integral appear ? It resembles some kind of folded normal distribution. By the way, you may take a look to my answer below.

First things first, notice that the integrand is even with respect to $x$, which allows to restrict the domain of integration to $\Bbb{R}_+$ and get rid of the absolute value in consequence, as it follows :
$$
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \int_{-c|x|}^{c|x|}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\, \exp\left(-\frac{x^2+(y-\theta)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) \\
   &= 2\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \int_{-cx}^{cx}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\, \exp\left(-\frac{x^2+(y-\theta)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) 
\end{align}
$$
You intended to use polar coordinates. With this in mind and given that $-cx \le y \le cx$, we understand that the domain of integration corresponds to a triangle delimited by the straight lines $y = \pm cx$, hence
$$
I = \frac{1}{\pi\sigma^2} \int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}r \int_{-\arctan c}^{\arctan c}\mathrm{d}\phi\; r\exp\left(-\frac{r^2 - 2\theta r\sin\phi + \theta^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)
$$
But I doubt this integral possesses a closed form.
Nonetheless, going back to cartesian coordiantes, we can "standardize" these gaussian integrals through the change of variables $x := \sigma u$ and $y := \sigma v + \theta$, hence
$$
\begin{align}
I &= 2\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\, e^{-\frac{1}{2}u^2} \int_{-cv-\frac{\theta}{\sigma}}^{cv-\frac{\theta}{\sigma}}\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\, e^{-\frac{1}{2}v^2} \\
  &= 2\int_0^\infty \phi(u) \left(\Phi\left(cu-\frac{\theta}{\sigma}\right) - \Phi\left(-cu-\frac{\theta}{\sigma}\right)\right) \mathrm{d}u \\
  &= 2\int_0^\infty \phi(u) \left(\Phi(cu+\mu) + \Phi(cu-\mu) - 1\right) \mathrm{d}u 
\end{align}
$$
where $\phi$ and $\Phi$ represent the PDF and CDF of the standard normal law respectively, we defined $\mu = \frac{\theta}{\sigma}$ and finally used the relation $\Phi(-x) = 1 - \Phi(x)$. It is to be noted that the function $\Phi$ may be replaced equivalently by the error function. Usually, you can refer to compiled tables of such integrals (such as this one for instance) and deduce new expressions with the help of integration by parts of differentiation with respect to parameters (such as $c$). Even if a lot can be done in this manner, unfortunately, it seems that the present integral cannot be simplified substantially, since
$$
\int_0^\infty \phi(t)\Phi(\alpha t + \beta) \,\mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{2}\Phi\left(\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}}\right) + T\left(\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{1+\alpha^2}},\alpha\right),
$$
where $T$ is a special function, named Owen's $T$ function, hence finally :
$$
I = 4\,T\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{1+c^2}},c\right)
$$
Nevertheless, it has to be highlighted that the case $\mu = 0$ is well-known (see here for example), based on
$$
\int_0^\infty \phi(at)\Phi(bt) \,\mathrm{d}t = \frac{1}{2\pi|a|}\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + \arctan\frac{b}{|a|}\right),
$$
whence
$$
I(\mu = 0) = 2\int_0^\infty \phi(u) \left(2\Phi(cu)-1\right) = \frac{2}{\pi} \,\arctan c.
$$

With $B$ the truth function of a logical condition defining areas.
$$\begin{align}\int_{\mathbb R^2}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 \sigma ^2}} e^{-\frac{(y-\theta )^2}{2 \sigma ^2}} B(-| c x| <y<| c x| )\ dy \ dx \\
\int \int e^{-\frac{x^2}{2 \sigma ^2}} e^{-\frac{y^2}{2 \sigma ^2}} B(-| c x| <\theta +y<| c x| )\ dy \ dx \\
\int _0^{\infty }\int _{-\pi }^{\pi }e^{-\frac{s}{2 \sigma ^2}} B\left(-\left| c\ \sqrt{s} \ \cos (\phi )\right| -\theta <\sqrt{s} \ \sin (\phi )<\left| c \ \sqrt{s} \ \cos (\phi )\right| -\theta \right)\ ds \ d\phi\\
\int _0^{\infty }\int _{-\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\ e^{-\frac{s}{2 \sigma ^2}} \ B\left(-c \ \sqrt{s} \ \cos (\phi ) - \theta <\sqrt{s} \ \sin (\phi )<c \ \sqrt{s} \ \cos (\phi )-\theta \right)ds \ d\phi \\+\int _0^{\infty }\int _{\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\frac{3 \pi }{2}}\ e^{-\frac{s}{2 \sigma ^2}} \ B\left(c \sqrt{s} \ \cos (\phi )-\theta <\sqrt{s} \  \sin (\phi )<-c \ \sqrt{s}\ \ \cos (\phi )-\theta \right)dsd\phi
\end{align}$$
Probably, it's not a greater problem to further subdivide the signs for the $\cos,\sin$ and do the integrals with the generated boundaries.

$B$ is indeed the Iverson Bracket. See this too.

Thanks for your reply! The problem now is that you have the $\theta$, so when you  divide by $cos(\phi)$, it is not possible to obtain the explicit extremes of integration. Without the $\theta$, you would have an expression for the extremes of integration of the inner integral involving $arctan$ function. Am I right?

You have to solve for the equalities as boundaries
$$  c \sqrt s  \cos \phi - \theta = \sqrt s \  \sin \phi$$
$$s\to \frac{\theta ^2}{(c \cos (\phi )-\sin (\phi ))^2}$$
